# How to get .toggleClick to return toggle with different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a column of boxes with the same class. I'm using a Toggle Click plugin to animate a box `left: 100px` when it is clicked and then to animate back to its starting position if it is clicked again. This works fine, but I would like to be able to have the other boxes also act as a trigger for the original box's animation back to its starting position as well as animate itself.

In short, I never want more than one box to be animated to the left. In essence, any clicking any box would toggle a box that has already animated. I'm hoping that the toggleClick script provides a built in way to handle this functionality. However, I'm not skilled enough in Javascript to be able to tell if this is possible or not.

Here's a JSFiddle of a very simplified version of what I'm trying to do. My real code has many different animations that will have to toggle, so any lean solution would be preferable.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/qusBw/2/

***PLUGIN***

```
// TOGGLE-CLICK SCRIPT //

    $.fn.toggleClick = function(){
        var methods = arguments, // store the passed arguments for future reference
        count = methods.length; // cache the number of methods 
        //use return this to maintain jQuery chainability
        return this.each(function(i, item){
            // for each element you bind to
            var index = 0; // create a local counter for that element
            $(item).click(function(){ // bind a click handler to that element
                return methods[index++ % count].apply(this,arguments); // that when called will apply the 'index'th method to that element
                // the index % count means that we constrain our iterator between 0 and (count-1)
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ksMZ7/ Hope this fix your need! `:)` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use toggleClick in this case, a custom click implementation is enough

```
var $boxes = $(".box").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        left = parseFloat($this.css('left')) || 0;
    if (left == 0) {
        $this.stop(true).animate({
            left: "100px"
        });
        $boxes.not(this).stop(true).animate({
            left: 0
        });
    } else {
        $this.stop(true).animate({
            left: 0
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SgDwn/)

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how this works a little bit. In particular, why did you made a variable for `$(this)` and what is the purpose of the parseFloat line? I think it is used to separate the `left` property value from the 'px' that would get returned with it, but I don't understand what the `|| 0` is for. I wasn't aware that a variable could be two things.

Comment: @UncleSlug the variable `$this` is created because we are using `$(this)` multiple times in the code, so it will be better to cache its value using a variable

Comment: @UncleSlug `parseFloat($this.css('left')) || 0` - yes the parseFloat() is used to get a numerical representation of the left value, the `|| 0` is used because when the page loads the `left` has a value of `auto` so the parseFloat() will return a `NaN` value, in that case we need to change the if condition to check for both `0` and `NaN`, instead we assign the value `0` if the first part of the `||`(or) condition is false

Comment: So, you're saying that if a logical operator is used in a variable, it makes the variable a condition? Thanks for all your help, it's been really valuable.